# How to change the background color of the tooltip only in grid in Kendo UI MVC?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my page,I use tooltip which class name is `.tooltipcell` to the grid cell,and also use tooltip which class name is `.tooltipbtn` to the button.Now I want to change the background color of the tooltip in grid,but I do not want to affect the background color of the button tooltip.How to do that?I use to codes below,it affects the two tooltip.

**method1:both effect**

```
.k-widget.k-tooltip{
background-color:red; //set the desired color
}
```

**method2:both effect**

```
div .k-widget.k-tooltip{
background-color:red; //set the desired color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
 show: function (e) {
        e.sender.popup.element.addClass('red-tooltip');
    },
```

and CSS

```
.red-tooltip {
    background-color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.tooltipcell{background-color:green;}

.tooltipbtn{background-color:green;}
```

Just incase your div .k-widget.k-tooltip might overwrite the style you may have to target it deeper like this:

```
div .k-widget.tooltipcell{background-color:green;}

div .k-widget.tooltipbtn{background-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is an amendment to MarioD Answer.

I didn't test it but given that it works, a better practice would be to concatenate these classes. It saves size in the css and improves loading time. Do this:

```
div .k-widget.tooltipcell, div .k-widget.tooltipbtn {
      background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: I try,but your codes seems not to change the tooltip's background-color,it is to change the cell's background-color.

Comment: Like I said, I was assuming MarioD code works. But I'll do my own testing and edit my answer. Meanwhile, it will help if you pull the HTML source just for this part. Or I will have to create a general example

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I was using kendo tooltip. I wanted to change the CSS of the tooltips only in one place leaving the rest of the tooltips intact.

Using css the normal way to do this would be to use target `.widget and .k-tooltip` CSS classes.

Although this would change all the tooltips within a page.

So, since I wanted to change only one tooltip (same problem as this post) I had to do a JS approach. 
So, I had to use the show function of kendo's tooltip. 
Example:

```
                   $('.target')..kendoTooltip({
                        position: 'bottom',
                        showAfter: 1000,
                        content: 'test',
                        function(e) {
                            e.sender.popup.element.addClass('customClass');
                            }
                    }).data('kendoTooltip');
```

I will try to post here a jsfiddle in few moments.

André

Answer (score 0):

You can do use ng-deep followed by the class name of the tooltip you would like to effect as follow:

```
::ng-deep .tooltipcell .k-tooltip {
  background-color: desired-color;

  .k-callout {
    color: desired-color;
  }
}
```